# What is the Maximum Size that a Text datatype can accept in Map Reduce program?

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

In order to execute a word Count Map Reduce program, we use Text as the datatype for the value parameter in the Key Value Pair. What is the maximum size the Text object can accept?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Apache Documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html), **The type of length is integer.**

Hence, I would suspect it would be whatever the maximum value of Integer be (most cases it is 2^31 - 1 characters which is around 4GB).

However, it would also be limited by the *input splits of your mapreduce job* if you are taking the 'value' from the input file.